# Timer every second for a few seconds

Tags: javascript

I am trying working on a few tests on a small game in Javascript. I want to make it so a button has a timeout for "X" seconds. I did this but it won't live update with the amount of time left.

Javascript:

```
function cd(button, x) {
    var ms = x * 1000;             //Change the seconds to Milliseconds
    var oldValue = button.innerHTML;

    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    button.innerHTML = oldValue +  " [" + x + "]";


    setTimeout(function(){
        button.innerHTML = oldValue;
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, ms);

}
```

Function Call:

```
cd(document.getElementById("click"), 5);
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="click" onclick="cd(this)">Get a banana</button>
```

I tried to combine the two to make it so that it would update every second with setInterval for "x" seconds, but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4nv7rnLv/3/)

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// store the oldValue here
var oldValue = null;

function cd(button, x) {
    var ms = x * 1000;

    // if you dont do this, you will get "Get a banana [5] [4] etc..."
    if(!oldValue){
        oldValue = button.innerHTML;
    }

    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);

    button.innerHTML = oldValue +  " [" + x + "]";

    setTimeout(function(){
        // decrease x
        x--;
        if(x > 0){
            cd(button, x);
        }else{
            // remove attribute
            button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            // change back to oldValue
            button.innerHTML = oldValue;
            //reset oldValue
            oldValue = null;
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Of course! Let me know if you need anything else or further explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the same thing that you want but using `setInterval`

http://jsfiddle.net/wgy3wntm/

Comment: After the second time of clicking the button. Adding the onclick. It becomes active every other second. Is there a fix to this? http://jsfiddle.net/Xearta/wgy3wntm/2/